# Add Custom Properties with Sequential Names

Tags: python

Blender 3.0

What I am creating is an operator which creates a custom property and sets a bunch of variables. Specifically changing type to float array, subtype to linear color, and is_library_overrideable = true. The below script works great for that but only if we are using one custom property named "test".

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

float_array = "test"
obj[float_array] = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
obj.id_properties_ensure()
property_manager = obj.id_properties_ui(float_array)
obj.property_overridable_library_set('["test"]', True)
property_manager.update(
    default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), 
    min=0.0, 
    max=1.0, 
    soft_min=0.0, 
    soft_max=1.0, 
    subtype="COLOR",
```

In the regular custom property operator, when you click 'new' a bunch of times, it creates a new custom prop each time and names them prop, prop1, prop2, etc:

[image]

So with my example script, what would I do so that if this operator is run multiple times, it creates new props each time and names them test1, test2, test3, etc.?

Comment: use `CollectionProperty()` https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.CollectionProperty